# How to get Specific Columns from Sql server in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

**AppDbContext.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EduManSystems.Model
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Student_master { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**IStudentRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EduManSystems.Model
{
    public interface IStudentRepository
    {
        Student GetStudent(string id);
        IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents();
        //Student GetStudents();
        Student Add(Student student);
    }
}
```

**SqlStudentRepository.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Common;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace EduManSystems.Model
{
    public class SqlStudentRepository : IStudentRepository
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext context;

        public SqlStudentRepository(AppDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public Student GetStudent(string id)
        {
            return context.Student_master.Find(id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            return context.Student_master.FromSql("select * from student_master").ToList();
        }
     }
}
```

**StudentController.cs**

```
using EduManSystems.Model;
using EduManSystems.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EduManSystems.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IStudentRepository _studentRepository;
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;

        public StudentController(IStudentRepository studentRepository,
                                    IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _studentRepository = studentRepository;
            this.hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

       [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var model = _studentRepository.GetStudents();
            return View(model);
        }

       [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult StudentList()
        {
            var model = _studentRepository.GetStudents();
            return Json(model);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

i tried this one, but i got error like this,

[image]

Hi Folks,

I need your help. Here, it retrieves all the data from SQL server(Raw sql queries or Linq). But, I need only specific columns like, select stud_first_name,stud_last_name from student_master;

The SQL query must return all the columns of the table. e.g. `context.Student_Master.FromSql("Select Stud_First_Name, Stud_Last_Name from Student_Master).ToList()` will throw an exception.

please help me

Thank You,

Comment: also can you please add `Student` class code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sample below to get the property names of entity:

```
 var names = typeof(User).GetProperties()
                            .Select(property => property.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have mapped you db structure right, you don't need `.FromSql`, just `ToList` should be sufficient enough, secondary you can do `context.Student_master.Select(s=> ...).ToList()`

UPD

From the comment:

You need to introduce new class which contains only needed subset of fields or (bad option) do `.Select(s => new Student { Stud_First_Name = s.Stud_First_Name , Stud_Last_Name = s.Stud_Last_Name })`

Comment: m already tried this one. but, i got return error like anonymous type(Cannot implicitly convert......)

Comment: Yes, cause your `IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()` should return enumerable of `Student`. So either you introduce new class which contains only needed subset of fields or (bad option) do `.Select(s => new Student { Stud_First_Name = s.Stud_First_Name , Stud_Last_Name = s.Stud_Last_Name  })`

Comment: bro, its working fine....  .Select(s => new Student { Stud_First_Name = s.Stud_First_Name , Stud_Last_Name = s.Stud_Last_Name })....Thank you so much

Comment: bro,mark will accepts after 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            return context.Student_master.Select(s => new Student { Stud_First_Name = s.Stud_First_Name, Stud_Last_Name = s.Stud_Last_Name });
        }
```

now its working fine both View and Json

Thank you so much Guru Stron.....